# Shippo Tracking FeDex Error in Json Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, shippo

I was trying to use the project ShippingTesting in Visual Studio(C#). I tried `UPS` which works great.
But when I tried `FeDex`, it threw an error saying:

> "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException", " Additional information: Error converting value "PRE_TRANSIT" to type 'Shippo.ShippoEnums+TrackingStatus'. Path 'tracking_history[0].status',"

It looks like a JSON serialization issue. Will this be a constant issue with Fedex?
Thanks!

Comment: I tried another FEDEX tracking number and it works. looks like the first one has a status as 'PRE_TRANSIT'(status_details: Shipment information sent to FedEx) throw an error on the first one while this one doesn't have this status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'PRE_TRANSIT' was added as a possible status in the latest version of the API (it replaces the older initial 'UNKNOWN' status for when a label has been created but has not yet entered transit).

The C# library may need to be updated to support this additional mapping. As a workaround, you can pass an older API version in the header of your request (pre '2018-02-08') and this should return the old 'UNKNOWN' mapping.

Ref: https://goshippo.com/docs/changelog